# Convert a nested list to a nested linked list

Tags: python

I have a nested list like:

```
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['q', 'r'], ['z', 'a'], ['r', 's'], ['b', 'c']]
```

If it were a **6x2** array, there would be no repeated elements in either of the columns.

I want to combine sublists wherever possible by matching the first (last) element of each sublist with the last (first) last element of a different sublist, So I'd end up with something like

```
[['z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['q', 'r', 's']]
```

In the example, I'm using letters to represent elements, but in my real problem, there's actually no order relationship; e.g., I can't say `'a' < 'b'`

I can do this with an ugly while loop, but I was hoping for a pythonic way of doing it.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you trying to compare each list withing that example with the next one or are you trying to compare it with 'abc'? If it's the first thing, then I don't understand how you can tell which match goes to which sublist

Comment: What he's trying to do is clearer if written this way: `[[z a][a b][b c][c d][q r][r s]]` becomes `[[z a b c d][q r s]]`.

Comment: Are your elements hashable/immutable? (I.e. can they be used as dictionary keys?)

Comment: yes, they're strings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most straightforward way to do this in Python involves explicit while loops, but I don't think it necessarily needs to be terribly ugly:

```
def nested_linked(l):
    d = {a: b for a,b in l}
    rv = []
    while d:
        k = [k for k in d.keys() if k not in d.values()][0]
        rrv = [ k ]
        while k in d:
            nk = d[k]
            del d[k]
            k = nk
            rrv.append( nk )
       rv.append( rrv )
   return rv
```

(Not optimized since your example was 6x2 -- if your real data is much larger and this might be a bottleneck, you should clearly do the initial-key selection in a more efficient way.)

Answer (score 3):

A slightly faster/cleaner version of svk's;

```
def nested_linked(link_pairs):
    mapping = dict(link_pairs)
    linkss = []

    # Python2: for link in mapping.viewkeys() - mapping.viewvalues():
    for link in mapping.keys() - mapping.values():
        links = [link]

        while link in mapping:
            link = mapping[link]
            links.append(link)

        linkss.append(links)

    return linkss
```

Comment: I guess `mapping.viewkeys()` should be `mapping.iterkeys()`?

Comment: Nope. `.iterkeys` is pretty useless, btw. It was thrown away in Python 3 and `.viewkeys` became `.keys`.

Comment: Hm, i didn't know about this. Thanks. Though you should note that it's only for Python 2.7