# How to convert a list with duplicate elements into a linked list without?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a nested like this:

```
[5, 6], [5, 4], [5, 8], [2, 6], [6, 8], [1, 3]
```

What I want is a list with unique elements joined by the duplicate ones, like this:

```
[2, 6, 8], [1, 3]
```

and for

```
[5, 6], [5, 4], [5, 8]
```

this:

```
[5, [6, 4, 8]]
```

Overall result should look like this:

```
[[5, [6, 4, 8]], [2, 6, 8], [1, 3]]
```

What I tried doing was using the following algorithm from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918659/convert-a-nested-list-to-a-nested-linked-list) question on the site

```
pairs_to_link = [[5, 6], [5, 4], [5, 8], [2, 6], [6, 8], [1, 3]]

dict_mapping = dict(pairs_to_link)
final_list = []

for link in dict_mapping.keys() - dict_mapping.values():
    links = [link]

    while link in dict_mapping:
        link = dict_mapping[link]
        links.append(link)

    final_list.append(links)

print(final_list)
```

---

```
OUTPUT: [[1, 3], [2, 6, 8], [5, 8]]
```

and it does remove duplicates and also links them but not in a 'tree' manner that I want, i.e. it only works for `[1,3],[2,6],[6,8]` to make it like this `[1,3],[2,6,8]`

Comment: What should `[2, 6], [6, 8], [6,9]` become? What about `[2, 6], [2, 7], [7, 8], [7, 9]`?

Comment: First one should be like this : `[2, 6, [8, 9]]` and the second one should be like this : `[2, [6, 7, [8, 9]]]`. Keep linking them until we get a linked list where every element is unique.

Comment: Do you only "link" adjacent elements?

Comment: Yes. Think of it like a many-one on-to function with list[0] as the domain. Like if I had a `[2, 5], [5, 2]`, the result would be the same ie `[2,5],[5,2]`. But if I had `[2,5],[2,6]`, result would look like [2, [5,6]]. Also if I had `[2,5], [5,8],[5,9]`, result would be `[2, 5, [8,9]]`